# Is it possible to create a REDCap question that autofills based on previous answers?

Tags: redcap

I am working on a research project and I have an eligibility screener. I'd like to have a question at the end that is hidden from participants that shows "eligible - yes or no?" and autofills based on their questions to previous answers. Is this possible; if so, how could I set this up?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Most institutions prefer to have their REDCap admins answer these questions.  Were you able to reach one of them?

Comment: Following from @wibeasley's point, look for the big blue 'Contact REDCap Administrator' button in the bottom left of your project pages.

Answer (score 1):

You would set this field up as a calculated field, hiding it as necessary, and build the arithmetic from your inclusion/exclusion criteria such that it returns 1 for eligible and 0 for ineligible. You can then use this 'eligible' value for later conditional logic, branching logic, automated survey invitations, and so on.

For example, say your eligibility requirements were that the participant is 18 years or older, does not have type-1 diabetes, and has a BMI greater than 30. Your calculated field would be something like:

```
if([age] >= 18 and [t1_diabetes] = '0' and [bmi] > 30, 1, 0)
```